# I have problems with arrays

Tags: php, arrays

So, I want to have table with users name, grades and subjects. Table will display only his grades. So I'm generating subject in foreach loop and reading grades depending on his id.

For subject I want to have an array which will contain infos about subject (teacher, classroom, etc.)

For now I have this array:

```
$subjects = array();
$getSubjects = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM predmeti");
while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_array($getSubjects)) {
    $subjects[]= array(
        $subject['subject_name'] => array(
            'id' => $subject['id'],
            'name' => $subject['name'],
            'teacher' => $subject['teacher'],
            'short_name' => $subject['short_name'],
            'classroom' => $subject['classroom']
        )
    );
```

I know this isn't right. I can't get data for each subject.

Could you please help me?

Comment: It may be right, but it's hard to tell without seeing the structure of the `predmeti` table.

Comment: Tavle predmeti contains: id, ime, name, teacher, short_name, classroom.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? What isn't as you'd expect it to be?

Comment: I don't know how to use foreach loop to echo all subject names and infos

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the columns by name while `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns only an integer indexed array. Have you tried `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: Will try. But how do I get keys and values from an array? Name of subject is each time different.

Comment: how is subject_name stored in the db?

Comment: How do you mean that? It is a varchar, 3 length

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` defaults to returning both numeric and string keys.